# Reusable collection of components in Sitecore 8.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore

In Sitecore 8.1, is it possible to have a list of components that can be reused in multiple places throughout the site?

For example, in my site I have a side bar that contains a component that has a list of the most recent news, another component that has a list of current promotions, and another component that has an ad. Many of my pages will use this same side bar, but not all of them, so I do not want to put it in my layout. Rather than having to recreate this same side bar for each page, I would like to create it once in it's own container/component so I can then reuse that.

I cannot hardcode a component with the needed components in a view because I need other non-technical users to be able to change the contents as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. In fact, that is the recommended way of building Sitecore components. To have small atomic components that you compose to provide more complex user interfaces.

For situations like your Sidebar where you might want the complex component on many pages, you can use a module called [Composite Components](http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2015/11/03/sitecore-composite-components/). This module is available from the Sitecore Marketplace [here](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/C/Composite_components.aspx).

As an overview, the module allows you to build presentation from smaller atomic renderings and group them together into a more complex rendering, like a Sidebar. Then you can add that component easily to other pages by using a Datasource. I have found it very useful on many projects.

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you!